# iOS Uploading AVCapture Recorded Video to Server via AFNetworking 3.0 Multipart

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, afnetworking-3, avcapture

I record video thorough using AVCapture and pass that video url to next controller where i have AVPlayer, which play video fine and using this code to upload video on server, when i call this form viewDidAppear it is working fine but when i call this in button action request body is missing,meanig that server did not get the video.Any one have a idea what i missing or doing wrong.

```
-(void)uploadVideotoServer{



[userInfoDict setValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"latitude"] forKey:@"latitude"];
[userInfoDict setValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"longitude"] forKey:@"longitude"];

     _request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"serverURL" parameters:userInfoDict constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData){
    NSLog(@"\n\n requrst time out is%f\n\n", [_request timeoutInterval]);

    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:testPAth name:@"video" fileName:@"myvideo.mov" mimeType:@"video" error:nil];

    NSLog(@"\n video yp upload %@\n\n",_videoUrl);
    // got video video url like this
   //file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3870C653-DAF9-484C-B51E-F30D8239E6F3/tmp/output7.mov
} error:nil];

[self.view addSubview:_playerProgress];


AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

_uploadTask = [manager
              uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:_request
              progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress)

              {

                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    [_playerProgress setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];

                      NSLog(@"\nuploading video vlaues %f\n",uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);

                  });
              }

              completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                  if (error) {
                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);


                      [_playerProgress setHidden:YES];

                  } else
                  {

                      NSLog(@"%@ ", response);


                      [_playerProgress setHidden:YES];

                      NSLog(@"\n\n REsponse Form Server %@\n\n",responseObject);

                  }
              }


               ];

[_uploadTask resume];


}
```

Comment: What does your console say? Did you check that when you press the button a file exists at _videoUrl?

Comment: using same url i am playing video in AVPlayer .

Comment: @otusweb thanks for pointing me towards right direction. i trace the the issue,actullay i am using  singleton class to save temporary video to photo library.In which i used completionBlock when i call videoUploading method in viewDidLoad that block is active and video exits at URL and when i call from button action on that time block execution became completed and temporary video been removed form that URL.

Comment: Glad i could help:-)

Answer (score 0):

change this :

```
[formData appendPartWithFileURL:testPAth name:@"video" fileName:@"myvideo.mov" mimeType:@"video/quicktime" error:nil];
```

Comment: did you try  upload using NSDATA ?

Comment: did't try with NSData let me try and will tell you.